# Why does irr(a,F(b)) divide irr(a,F)?

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

My textbook asserts, as part of a proof about totally inseparable extensions, the following:

Let F be a field
Let a and b be elements of the algebraic closure of F such that they are separable over F
irr(a,F(b)) divides irr(a,F)

I do not understand why this is the case.

I see that irr(a,F) consists of factors whose zeros are not in F, and that irr(a,F(b)) consists of factors whose zeros are not in F(a), which is a bigger field.  So, each time we adjoin an element to the field under consideration, the irreducible polynomial of a given element over that field lowers in degree.  It wouldn't surprise me if this corresponded to the elimination of one or more factors of that polynomial, but I don't see why this has to be the case.  Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Observe that the division is in $\;\Bbb F(b)[x]\;$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\Bbb F\subset \Bbb F(b)\implies irr(a,\Bbb F)\,,\,irr(a,\Bbb F(b))\in\Bbb F(b)[x]$$

But $\;irr(a,\Bbb F(b))\;$ is **the** monic polynomial of *minimal degree* in $\;\Bbb F(b)[x]\;$ that has $\;a\;$ as a root and thus it divides *any* other polynomial in $\;\Bbb F(b)[x]\;$ that has $\;a\;$ as a root...

Comment: Did you not use the separability hypothesis?

Comment: @BillDubuque, no I didn't, and as far as I can see, it is unnecessary..isn't it? I'd appreciate any correction otherwise.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is unnecessary.  This showed up twice, once in a proof involving separable extensions and once in a proof involving totally inseparable extensions.  I threw it in just in case I was missing something.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's exactly what I needed.